# What is the $E$-r.e. part of $L$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory

*See Sacks' paper [*$E$-recursive inuitions*](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Esacks/erecint.pdf) or his [book](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/Chapter/Chapter-X-E-Closed-Structures/pl/1235422642) for background on $E$-recursion. Throughout, work in $\mathsf{ZFC+V\not=L}$. I'll use $\varphi_e$ in place of $\{e\}$ for the $e$th partial $E$-recursive function in some appropriate enumeration.*

Divergence in $E$-recursion is equivalent to ill-foundedness of the associated computation tree. Consequently, Mostowski absoluteness implies that $L$ is not $E$-r.e.: if $dom(\varphi_e)\not=V$ then we can reflect the statement "$\exists x(\varphi_e(x)\uparrow)$" to $L$.

Now let $\mathbb{E}$ be the union of the transitive $E$-r.e. subclasses of $L$. I recall seeing (but can't track down) short arguments that $\mathbb{E}$ itself is not $E$-r.e. and that $\mathbb{E}\subsetneq L$, neither of which is obviously true (at a glance the second point should be a corollary of Sacks' [stronger argument](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44161539#metadata_info_tab_contents) that $L$ is not $E$-r.e. in any element of $L$, but I think that's overkill). I'm curious whether my recollection is correct:

> Is it in fact the case that $\mathbb{E}$ is a non-$E$-r.e. proper subclass of $L$?